# Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Why does this code give me this error? How to fix it?

> Error : "[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)"

and this is my json

```
[{"id":1,"title":"title","message":"content","isSent":true,"datePublished":"2019-05-13T15:06:40+02:00","messageType":1,"dateExpired":"2019-05-13T15:06:40+02:00","imageUrl":"http:\/\/\/img\/admin\/login.jpg"},{"id":2,"title":"Tytu\u0142 test","message":"Yeah","isSent":true,"datePublished":"2019-05-13T15:11:12+02:00","messageType":1,"dateExpired":"2019-05-13T15:11:12+02:00","imageUrl":"http:\/\/\/img\/admin\/login.jpg"}]
```

```
final response = await http.get("http:/abc/posts/get");
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    list = json.decode(response.body) as List;
    firstList = json.decode(response.body) as List;
  setState(() {
    isLoading = false;
  });
} else {
  Toast.show('Failed to load data', context);
  throw Exception('Failed to load data');
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the error you are getting?

Comment: @Xcode this is the error "[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)"

Comment: Trim your input. If you are entering a String and try changing the keyboardType to text

Comment: @Xcode didn't work